# Google Java API to list users in a company

Tags: java, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am trying to list the users in a company by using the Java SDK. The code that I am trying is:

```
try {
httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId("xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER))
                .setServiceAccountUser("adminuser@myTestDomain.com")
                .build();


Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName("My App Name")
            .build();

Users result = null;
result = directory.users().list().setDomain("myTestDomain.com").execute();
}
```

I have a Private key string which has like:

```
key = new String("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
+"blah1\n"
+"blah2\n"
+"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");
```

Now how do I get the Google credential to be built with the above 'key' string as the PrivateKey and be able to list the users. I have tried, reading the string as a byte array, reading it from a file etc. but all of those have failed with one error or the other.

I just need to get the list of users in the domain myTestDomain.com for which adminuser@myTestDomain.com is the administrator. I am able to successfully get the same with the following Go code btw. I am struggling with only the Java code. Any pointers ? Thanks.

Go code:

```
    conf := &jwt.Config{
        Email: "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        PrivateKey: []byte(`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
blah1
blah2
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`),
        Scopes:   []string{admin.AdminDirectoryUserScope},
        TokenURL: google.JWTTokenURL,
        Subject: "adminuser@myTestDomain.com",
    }

    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)
    srv, _ := admin.New(client)
    u, _ := srv.Users.List().Domain("myTestDomain.com").Do()
    fmt.Println(u.Users)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the JSON service account key that you download from [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts?project=_) directly:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("myFile.json"));
credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(is, httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY)
    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER));
```